# Mysql Query and add the values of the field (Parent, Child) DB structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Scenario:

I have two tables `(Parent and Child relationship) = (tblreqslip, tblreqdetails)`

```
tblreqslip = column fields (parent_id, client_name, date)
tblreqdetails = column fields (child_id, parent_id, subtotals)
```

Needs help:

> In getting all the values in my child table (field ="subtotals") and
>   add them all up "simple addition Math function".

Note: My child tblreqdetails field =(differ in values) Ex: Parent ID no="1" has child field value of 10 subtotal fields, Parent ID no="2" has a child field value of 15 subtotal fields.

Here is where I am stuck at:

```
$p_id=$_GET['parent_id']; //get from Post URl
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblreqdetails WHERE child_id='$p_id'";
$select = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rw = mysql_fetch_array($select);
```

(I am loosing a line here to get the values from "subtotal" field, ADD them all up no matter how many are the subtotal values in the field and just echo the TOTAL amount)
Ex: ID="1" $TOTAL value =(200.50 + 1000 + 3000 .... so on till how many subtotal my child table has a value depending on my Parent ID)

Thanks so Much in Advance.

Comment: First, this is odd, normally your subquery would be `SELECT * FROM tblreqdetails WHERE parent_id='$p_id'";` or something like that...  child has both an localID and parentID.  parent probably just localID.  etc.

Comment: Thanks ebyrob. How should I correct this? and get the all subtotals from my child table and add them all up?

Comment: For starters, show in your question all columns for both tables (or at least all relevant columns) so we can be sure what's going on.  I'm thinking you'll have to change a column definition, but I don't know that without seeing the table definitions.  There should be  simple direct relationship between tblreqslip and tblreqdetails.

Comment: Sure.. Editing original post now..

Comment: Sir PM 77-1 already edited the post. Thanks Sir..

Comment: You'll have to go ahead and over-write that.  PM 77-1 made some pretty formatting changes, but they don't clear up your table definitions.

Comment: there you go Sir ebyrob.. I have edited it now..

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM tblreqdetails WHERE parent_id='$p_id'";` and don't call me Sir :-)   (PS - It can all be done in a single SQL query, but do what you're doing for now, it should work!)

Comment: Oh thank you! :) then how can I add the values from my "subtotal" field? is there a query or code for me to add all the values from my field "subtotal"? base on my parent_id? Just a simple ADD math function so I can Echo the Total amount of all subtotals..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you have these two tables:

```
tblreqslip
+++++
 ID +
+++++
  1 |
  2 |
  3 |

tblreqdetails
++++++++++++++++++++++
child_id | subtotals +
++++++++++++++++++++++
  1      |  4500     |
  1      |  6000     |
  2      |  3000     |
  3      |  1500     |
  3      |  1000     |
```

**UPDATED**
Try this, it works with me:

```
$p_id=$_GET['parent_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblreqdetails WHERE child_id='$p_id'";
$select = mysql_query($query) ;
$i = 0;
while ($rw = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
$i++;
$subtotals[$i] = $rw['subtotals'];
}
$TOTAL = array_sum($subtotals); // sum all the subtotals field with selected child_id
echo "id : $p_id total is ".$TOTAL;
```

Now, you got the TOTAL of subtotals.

Comment: Got this error :( "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\preq_content.php on line 17"

Comment: move `$rw = mysql_fetch_array($select)` into `while()` function. It works with me. I'll update the answer

Comment: Can't wait for your edit :) will let you know if it works.. :)